# How do I write a good answer to a question?

Tags: support, faq, answers

Are there guidelines for what constitutes a good answer?  Let's discuss.  Perhaps, we can come up with some ideas for the FAQ.

Building off [Should the official FAQ include information on how to answer as well as ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7652/should-the-official-faq-include-information-on-how-to-answer-as-well-as-ask-quest)

> For more information, see ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**How to Write a Good Answer**

- Be clear.
- Be accurate and correct.
- Provide examples.
- Link to more information and further reading.
- Quote relevant material to keep the user from having to click on every link given to get basic information.
- Revise your answer to include more information as it comes along.
- Be sure to monitor your answer for comments so that you can reply with explanation if questions come around about your answer.
- Don't duplicate other answers.
- Actually answer the question. Do not post an answer stating you have the same problem or one which only answers a question different from the one that was asked.

Comment: Could you provide some examples and links to further reading?

Comment: @JoshDM  [Link to more information and further reading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/326090).

Comment: An [abc for LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6598/93818) has plenty of relevant material and links (for the question from that SE site). That may serve as an example, even if off site, of being clear, with examples, and a bit of quirkynes that may, or may not, add some fun and ammenity to an answer.

Answer (score 38):

I [blogged about this](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) a while ago. The bullet points from that article:

- Read the question (carefully)
- Code is king
- Answer the question *and* highlight side-issues
- It's okay to guess, but be honest
- Raise the overall accuracy level
- Provide links to related resources
- Care about your reader: spelling, grammar and style matter
- A time-limited answer may be better than no answer at all
- Don't be afraid to delete (or edit heavily) useless answers
- Be polite
- Don't "answer and run"
- Have fun

(Obviously the post goes into rather more depth on all of them :)

You might also want to read the answers to [this rather similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527962) (now deleted; visible to those with 10k+ rep).

Answer (score 17):

Good answers do more than simply reference an external site and suggest that the OP refer to it.  Answers that primarily reference an external site should include a summary of the information so that it becomes a primary source as well as a reference.  This will help the answer to stand the test of time.

Comment: It is also good for situations where the provided link becomes invalid.

Answer (score 12):

Don't just provide the code which solves the problem - try to help the OP understand this code as well, and why it works.  This also helps others who come along afterwards.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer has good points, but I think an important one is missing:

- Keep to the point; the answer should be as brief as possible for a complete answer. Don't write about other things than what the question asked for.