# How to anwer on Stackoverflow? Any guidelines?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

I made a quick glance at both small and big FAQs but no luck.
Both explains how to ask, not answer.
But are there any guidelines how to answer? What I can do and what I can't?

All right, I should be more specific.

From my experience (may be yours too), I can tell that sometimes there is a big difference between what one *asks*, what they *want* and what they *need*.

So, 2 more specific questions:

1. Am I **ought** to provide a literal answer if I am sure that question is wrong?
2. Same as above but if there is already a dozen of literal answers?

Is there any written rule that orders me to answer wrong question, before I can tell a better way to solve a whole problem? (I can be wrong with my guess, yes. And sometimes I am. But that's another matter. It can be treated as any other wrong answer. But what's wrong with it if it's just answer)

I am just wondering why everyone believe that only literal and direct answers are allowed?

Comment: There's already an FAQ started -- see the link added by my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two aspects

- The mechanical ([formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) etc)
- The more "what kind of answer should I give" aspect

I had a stab at answering the latter in a [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully) a while ago.