# Why do I get negative votes on all of my questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, down-votes

I'm actually speaking about Stack Overflow. I'm afraid to ask questions because I always seem to get negative votes and my questions get closed before I get my answer.

I actually want to improve my question-asking pattern, so I'd like to get some input on the following two matters:

1. What are the reasons for my negative votes?
2. What can I do to get rid from them?

I checked these two links and always try to follow the steps mentioned there:

1. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
2. [How to ask questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/how-to-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: When you ask things like "step by step direction for beginner" it really looks too broad. This site is for asking question, not writing manuals. Sometimes you don't look like you know what you are doing, and only have one question in the process. When you look clueless, you will get downvotes.

Comment: The only place where I see "all time I get negative" vote is meta - and those were previous incidents (months ago) of you getting question banned.

Comment: As for your latest question on SO, "@downvoters , do You have answer of this question? or any comment? if not then who give you permission to downvote this question." The system gives them permission to downvote regardless of whether they have answers or comments. "No need to give upvote or any positive feedback." But we are not allowed to give you downvotes or negative feedback?

Comment: related: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thank you all for Your valuable information.

Comment: yaa user's(down-voters) usually do it like hobby when they are mad!! Ignore them. :)

Comment: *all time I get negative vote*: please show an example of question.

Comment: [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44189/225745) seems relevant. All issues in your posts was discussed already, so first subsection (search) matters. And of course you failed at *Don't Whine or Complain* part.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @Bala while I agree that Meta downvotes are not always something to worry about, stating that it's because users do it as a hobby because they are mad is simply ridiculous.

Comment: @Bala On Meta downvotes means "I disagree", so it's not a hobby, it's a simple case of people who examined OPs posts and find it unfair on his side to grumble about what happens with them.

Comment: @Mołot down-vote for asking basic question is not fair - Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange family of Q&A sites. I don't see any wrong with this post and please think of the question title, it really hurts the user for downvote.

Comment: @Bala [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), please don't forget that. Downvotes **does not** mean something is wrong with the post itself. Only lack of usefulness. And he is exaggerating a bit, and he claims to read howtos but still asks for manuals etc... So this is unuseful question, as any answer would need to contain what he supposedly already knows but ignored.

Comment: @Bart: He's right though. Who among us on meta is rational?

Comment: No no no @BoltClock'saUnicorn. The others are the strange ones. We're all perfectly SQUIRREL!!

Comment: as far as I can tell, you've got a [reasonable request for assistance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info). Gang of brainless downvoters piling on it seems to be just too lazy to address it with an answer / comment or with a pointer to a duplicate post. This is a known dark side of meta, see eg **[Voting on Meta is not just for (dis)agreement...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191880/165773)** (this comment will be most likely flagged and deleted by the same gang of brainless voters but oh well)

Comment: @gnat but it's not a support request, just discussion. And seeing what  [BoltClock's a Unicorn wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212064/why-i-get-negative-vote-in-all-of-my-question#comment682098_212064), OP already had couple incident of question ban and got assisted out of them... so what's the usefulness of asking again? (note, no downvote from me here, I just kinda understand where they came from) Also, consider rewording your comment, now it fits " rude or offensive" flag way too well.

Comment: @Mołot FWIW [your comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212064/why-i-get-negative-vote-in-all-of-my-question?noredirect=1#comment682097_212064) here looks all right  to me: thoughtful and with substantial effort involved into explaining things to asker

Comment: @Bala - I too have experienced down votes on SO probably by someone who's stats show he is making 100's of downvotes a week, who's comments revealed he did not even begin to understand the question, and who apparently invited his other down-voting friends to come and down vote my question more when I tried to correct his understanding - he also edited my question incorrectly as well and then complained my question did not have the needed detail - that he had just edited out! Yeah. Must be a hobby. SO has a high-rep revenge voting ego user problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your question contains the following line:

> **NOTE:- please don't negetive vote or close this ticket. I really want to learn node.js. and I didn't find my question's appropriate answer.**

Ya might attract downvotes.  It also should make you think about ***why*** you added that to your question.  You already knew your question was of low quality, but you still asked it.

In future, if you know your question is going to stink, don't post it.  Instead, research your problem more.  Try different things.  Keep track of what you did so you can add this information to your question.  This will help improve the quality greatly.

Answer (score 18):

Consider [node.js - issues I fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628034/node-js-need-help-for-below-cases).

First we have a giant, pointless, screen-shot. Then we have a multiple questions that all add up to 'help me get off the ground with node.js'. You could just as well have written:

> I've heard there's this thing called node.js. Where can I learn what it's useful for
>   and how to write code for it?

This is all off-topic -- this site is not a place to ask for tutorials, or pointers to tutorials. If you'd gone and read any of the many tutorials and then come back with a specific question, there'd be no downvotes or close votes.

Comment: First of all, that giant screenshot points to node.js command prompt. I don't think this screenshot is meaningless. because - if I don't attach this screenshot , then someone will ask "show what You have tried". So in my question , I have tried to complete 2 things. 1) what I have done and 2) what I am looking for.

Comment: @ripa, people here don't like screenshots. You could just as well have said, 'I tried to execute ....' in text. Second, that's not going to register with most people here as enough of a try. Just trying to puit you in the picture.

Comment: not getting Your above comment. what do You mean by "Just trying to puit you in the picture"?

Comment: @ripa - [This is an idiom](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/put+you+in+the+picture.html)