# Smart answers howto

Tags: discussion, answers

A document that helped me a lot is [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by ESR.

How do I **answer** questions the smart way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ask a smart question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)

Comment: Oh, I just re-read your question - I'd revoke my close vote if I could, sorry

Comment: @Blorgbeard, Not a duplicate of my question. This is about answering a good way, not about asking the right way.

Comment: Related: [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204)

Comment: Also, see a blog post from Jon Skeet on the subject: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx

Comment: Upvoted all comments, thank you for your feedback I am gratified for following the advices you linked. Except that i don't post incomplete answers because I feel that would be annoying for the TO.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow these steps to answer a question:

1. **Read the question** (don't skim titles).
2. Post an answer, which contains:

   - The answer to the question
   - Properly formatted text (Utilise markdown, without exaggerating).
3. Submit answer
4. Edit answer to polish it:

   - Include relevant links to (external) sources, if applicable.
   - Mention possible pitfalls. *"Beware, this solution might fail under the following conditions..."*, and possible solutions, *"... this can be avoided by ..."*.
   - Add live examples (if possible, such as [JSFiddle for JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net)).
5. Save edit
6. Check back after a while, to check whether the question (requirements) has changed (unfortunately, this happens a lot).

Obviously, the answer has to be correct. If you're getting unsure, do some research at Google.

When you discover that the answer is bad (misread question, wrong answer), delete the answer (even if it has some upvotes already). If you have a great solution, edit the answer while it's deleted, and finally undelete it.

Comment: I disagree with the practice of purposefully posting a known incomplete answer. Edits are inevitable, but if you have more to post and you *know* it, don't submit it until you are done.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I do not advocate posting incorrect/incomplete answers. I propose to submit the *right answer* (Code to `give me teh code` questions). Then, use the edit feature to explain the code for future readers.

Comment: I don't post incomplete answers but still since i follow your advice my answers are accepted with more success so thanks !