# How to increase StackOverflow reputation with just 2-3 hours to spare?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I am a StackOverflow user for almost two years(Proud to be so). But my reputation has not been increasing much. It is **3083** at present.

Although I know why that is so. I don't find enough time to go on StackOverflow. With work and family, I am not able to visit it every day. I try though to visit it on alternate days. That too for 2 may be 3 hours. I see people being member for just 3-4 months and acquire a huge reputation which really surprises me.

My question is how can I efficiently utilize the hours I visit on StackOverflow to increase my reputation?

Comment: @Downvoter : What's the reason?

Comment: Downvote, It's not me, So, what is the reason to increase reputation ?

Comment: @Lucifer : I am motivated and feel happy when my reputation is increased even by a single unit. As simple as that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: The linked dupe contains about all the legit stuff you can do. Good luck! :)

Comment: As for downvote(s) on your question it's because people think it's rant, simple as that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: If my question is being closed with the reason given, sp should be [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast) question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : How is my question rant? Did my question describe any anger?

Comment: @Nitish no, that other question describes in general how to gain reputation. You made your question personal saying about your own reputation and how it does not increase - that's why it can be considered rant.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "The linked dupe" doesn't contain only "legit stuff". I really don't like the advice it gives about downvoting competing answers, for example...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : You didn't get my question clearly. I have mentioned that how to increase(gain) reputation in a limited time of visiting the forum. How is it rant and I don't find any reason to close my question.

Comment: @Nitish I did understand and that's why I voted to close as duplicate. I also did not downvote.

Comment: @dystroy it's an old post feel free to comment there or flag to close it, that's not the issue here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : Is the reason to close my question "Duplicate"? Can you explain that? I find a different reason.

Comment: @Nitish the close mechanism might be confusing. If 3 users voted to close as "not constructive" and 2 voted to close as duplicate, the "not constructive" will be chosen. The first comment I made here is automatic and was created when I voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: @All other people who closed the question : I need an answer. Why my question has been closed. It is not at all fair to use your reputation this way.

Comment: @Nitish, the reason is already mentioned with the closure **closed as not constructvive question**.

Comment: @Lucifer : See comment 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw your profile, you are an iPhone developer. You need to read this question [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/173001). If you spend enough time for a single meaningful answer then you can earn good reputation.

Writing a good answer takes time, you need to visit old threads, read codes, read answer style.

Increment in the reputation benefits only for gain in the privileges and user trust.

Also visit [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/173001) ( I got it from above Sha Wiz Dow Ard's comment below your question. )

Comment: +1 for your second point.