# Will deleted answers to closed questions get undeleted when the question is reopened?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12599234/996493) that later got closed as a duplicate and my answer was deleted by a moderator.

After a while it was determined the question was not a duplicate and got reopened, but answer is not undeleted. How can I get my answer undeleted?

Comment: That's not a real answer. That's just a collection of links.

Comment: @Chichiray ok thanks, but the author of question had accepted that as an answer means he had got something usefully with the links right?

Comment: @iShru The above comment is from Chichiray not from Lucifer. :)

Comment: @hims056 oops :P now its corrected thanks

Comment: @iShru, see [How to write good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7693/173001)

Comment: @Lucifer Thanks :) im as happy as my answer is revoked.. what OP stand for ?

Comment: Isn't a deleted answer already revoked in a sense?

Comment: Stop posting the same link-only answer to the question.  It's **not** an answer and will be deleted.

Comment: @casperOne ok.. thanks , i will go through the links and will post the useful informations from the link as answers from next time

Comment: @iShru I've messaged the OP on the question, I believe this should be reclosed, I don't think he understands that it really is a duplicate.

Comment: My recommendation is to answer the question without referencing the other SO question.  It's noise and confusing the issue.  Elaborate the other links that you've referenced that don't point to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @casperOne what makes you think that question is a duplicate? frequent have asked about issue related to CSS Style background image in portrait mode not just about CSS background-position .. and my answer had an useful link for the question which was removed .. i agree to the point referencing the other SO question is noise and i will correct it..

Comment: I would vote to undelete if I could but can't because a moderator deleted it. The "duplicate" question has no answers, while that answer actually provides the OP with a place to look to get answers. If you can see the question, I'd recommend expanding it a bit to include the relevant pieces of css that fix the problem, then flag it for a moderator to undelete with a note that you expanded the link-only answer.

Comment: @Rachel The answers won't be undeleted, they are link only answers.  I see now that it's *not* a duplicate, so that issue is settled.  However, we're not allowing link only answers.  The answers must be able to stand alone without the link.

Comment: @casperOne How about undeleting it long enough for the person posting the answer to edit it into something that is not a link-only answer? I still think the links are useful since they do outline the exact problem (scalable background images in iOS), and its 4 links pointing to different resources for different solutions, not just a single link-only answer

Comment: @Rachel  No.  An answer that relies on multiple links is the same as one that provides a single link, in that there is *no* content but the links.  If the poster can edit their original answer and flag for moderator attention, then we can review it then, or the poster can put effort into a new, higher-quality answer which meets quality guidelines on Stack Overflow.  Either way, we don't let answers like that "breathe".

Comment: That's a shame because I'd take an answer with link that goes to solutions to my problem over no answer at all any day. I'm fairly sure the OP can't see their deleted answer, which is why I was asking for you to undelete it for a few hours so they can have a chance to edit it since it already is at a +2

Comment: @Rachel A deleted answer *can* be edited, IIRC.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Can people without 10k rep see deleted answers? In particular, the person who posted the answer?

Comment: @Rachel They can see it if they navigate to the question.

Comment: @Rachel thanks much for your support,  i have understood my mistake of merely providing links in answers and i have studied about question and have given my best effort for solution , if there are anything i have missed out in this recent answer please suggest me how i can improve it further..

Comment: @Rachel +2 is irrelevant, votes are not an indicator of quality.  Also, instead of editing the original answer (which the +2 is a copy of), they simply copied and pasted the answer again.  The OP of the answer is *clearly* aware that the other answer is deleted, but chose to instead just copy it wholesale instead of improving it.  This isn't the correct approach to this situation.

Comment: @casperOne sorry for reposting the deleted answer, i have understood my mistake of merely providing links in answers , i have come-up with new answer , please have a look at it and if i have missed out anything in my answer or if my approach of answering is wrong please suggest me the corrections so that i can contribute SO with better answers.

Comment: @casperOne I find + votes are usually an indicator of helpfulness, not quality. A +2 to me signifies that two people find the content of that answer useful, and by deleting it we are not *making the internet a better place*, which is one of SO's original goals. And I can understand not realizing you can edit and flag for undeletion. There was a time when I probably would have taken the exact same action when the "Undelete" button didn't work and I thought the answer was deleted because the question was closed.

Comment: @Rachel I'm willing to remove the validation of a link by two people in light of turning Stack Overflow into a link farm.

Comment: @Rachel: as I tried to explain you some days/weeks ago, Stack Overflow is **not** a discussion forum. Please try to get that association out of your head.

Comment: @Chichiray Ummm perhaps you have me mistaken for someone else? I'm very aware that SE is not a discussion forum and don't treat it as such. I like the way all posts are either Questions or Answers, and that the voting system is used to push the best Answers to the top. I even understand not wanting link-only answers, although I personally think an answer containing links to another place that describes the problem and solution in more detail is a valid answer to a question (and better than no answer at all), although admittedly not ideal since links can go bad and make that answer useless.

Answer (score 9):

I would say in this case, no, the answers will not be restored (I believe that's what you're going for).

The question is *not* a duplicate, but your link to the other question (saying it was like another question) is what caused the confusion over it being closed as such in the first place.

However, [link-only answers are not answers on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/140951) and are deleted.  We insist that you post an answer that doesn't rely on the link in question, so that if the link goes down, the answer is still viable even if the link is removed from the question.

Comment: okay so what are all the corrections i am supposed to do for the answer to be valid?  i have to explain link content to focus on solution right?

Comment: The answer should sufficiently answer the question without the need to click the links. Links are merely for support (documentation), background details (in depth tech) and extended/detailed information (complete running examples), etc. In other words, after removing the links from your answer, it should still answer the question in its *entirely*. Otherwise better just use comments or vote for close as dupe (if the links are on stack overflow itself).

Comment: ok @Chichiray thanks ..

Comment: I disagree with this. I think the answer should be undeleted long enough for the person posting it to edit the answer into a non-link-only answer. Obviously they came to meta for help and are aware of the problem with link-only answers, so why not undelete it for a few hours and to let them edit it? Also, its not like it was a single link answer. It contained 4 links, 3 of which went to solutions to the problem and 1 which went to a discussion on the problem.

Comment: @Rachel: deleted posts can still be edited by owner.

Comment: @Chichiray Ok, I thought you need 10k rep to see any deleted post, even your own

Comment: @Rachel: only if the Question is deleted.

Comment: @Chichiray Makes sense, thanks :)