# "Punchline" badge for outstanding upvotes/length ratio

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Please consider introducing a badge for highly acclaimed yet terse answers. The ones with links in them should not, obviously, count.

You can introduce a hard metric - e. g. >=10 upvotes for an answer that's <100 characters long. Or you can count the "milliupvotes per byte" (so that's a reasonably sized integer) metric for an answer and grant the badge above a certain threshold.

And then the SO administration can gauge the quality of SO content in hard quantitative terms :)

Comment: +1, __Terseness should be appreciated.__  Of course I'm not sure how you'd be able to judge this in an automated fashion.

Comment: I thought [Terseness should be appreciated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166035/148949) sounded familiar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please no incentive for short answers. We have enough already.

---

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Would you like [one of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pith_helmet) for the next Season Bash, @Michael?

Comment: More screenshots! More red circles!

Comment: And under my suggestion, Mat would have a shiny new badge by now.

Comment: I'd already get one more if you accepted this answer. My point was that short (but accurate) answers already get a very large rep/word (and time spent) reward, plus the usual answer badges. No real point in giving more incentive, it's already well "incentivized". Emphasis should be put on the quality of the answers, not their length, IMO. (And short answers can be good, I appreciate to-the-point answers without "fluff".)