# Users fooling stackoverflow by highlighting jsfiddle links instead of an actual code

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

I just answered a question here and in the morning when I went back to the page,

[IE Issue - using a span in an anchor to make DIV clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15750298)

what I saw was that this particular user (Pavlo Shandro) is fooling the system by highlighting the links which system thinks is a code, so is this restriction spoiling the formatting of an answer? Because the highlight is meant for codes and not links

Also the answer doesn't serve the purpose of sharing the code instead he is ACTUALLY sharing only the link which makes the answer unusable if the link is dead

Comment: I doubt if jsfiddle links would be dead any time soon but clearly that should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You could flag it, or edit it. Not sure what you're saying is wrong though.

Comment: @Antony So in this case(If jsfiddle links are not deleted) I don't know why stackoverflow restricts the user to share the code, instead people are spoiling the answers formats by highlighting links

Comment: Because they don't answer the question. This isn't a Programmer-For-Hire site, it's a Q&A site. Answers have to explain the solution to the problem and why it worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They might be fooling the automatic low-quality answer detector, but they're not fooling Stack Overflow. Why? Because Stack Overflow is run by its users!

*You* noticed that it was a bad answer, and *you* have the power to do something about it. Here's a short list of your options; feel free to mix-and-match:

- Edit the answer yourself to improve it and turn it into a high-quality answer (if possible).
- Leave a comment to the answer, briefly explaining (as you did here) the problems with link-only answers and how it can be improved to be a better answer. If they don't find your brilliant prose convincing enough, hit them with [the rulebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and [the guidebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).
- Downvote the answer (because it is "not helpful" and/or "not useful").
- Flag the answer for moderator attention (if you truly think it is unsalvageable and needs to be hit with the delete hammer).
- Vote to delete the answer yourself (if you have [sufficient privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user)).

Comment: Wise enough :)  .