# Is it bad form to answer a jquery question with a plugin?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, jquery

When a question is asked relating to to jQuery to begin with, is recommending an existing plugin that does exactly what the OP is trying to do appropriate?

Why re-invent the wheel for basic stuff?

To use an analogy - 
If some one tells you they need something to beat nails into the wall.

Do you explain how to whittle a handle, forge a head, and put those things together to make a hammer?

OR

Do you just direct them to a toolbox and tell them to pick up a hammer?

And before the first response explains that in some cases you need a custom tool for a specific job, I'm not really speaking about those cases. I realize fully that plug-ins are not the cure all answer for everything.

Comment: Something tells me that someone downvoted/criticized an answer of yours that included a plugin as an answer. Am I correct? If so, please link to that example. It does little for us to argue in general terms. Personally, I find that a plugin (or a library) doesn't always work as it is documented, so if I suggest a plugin that I haven't personally used before and it doesn't work as documented, I'm ready for some down votes. That being said, talking about jQuery plugins is really abstract for me, I'm a Java developer mostly, and for all I know, jQuery plugins may be better than Java libraries.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk No criticism involved, just curious. [Here's the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018400/add-event-to-created-element/16108202#16108202) that led me to wonder about the issue.

Comment: Ah yes, in this case your solution seems to be the best and simplest. Just don't be disappointed if you don't get the bounty. The person asking the question probably already resolved his issue three or four days ago with one of the other answers provided.

Comment: I think this applies to Stack Overflow and the coding sites only, the question is prior to the MSE_MSO split.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 9):

> Do you just direct them to a toolbox and tell them to pick up a hammer?

If this person has never heard of a hammer before, just make sure you explain how to use it to solve their problem.  In other words, don't just link to the plugin, give an example showing how to use it to solve their specific problem.

Otherwise, no it's not bad form to direct people to existing solutions to their problems.

Comment: Not enough jquery in this answer, have you tried this jquery plugin for making magical layouts that look pretty? http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html It's pretty magical! And its JQUERY! I mean you can never have enough JQUERY.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can suggest an existing tool.

That said, you shouldn't just provide a link to some page as the entirety of your answer.  In addition to stating which tool that they should use make a point of including at least some additional information.  Explain how to use the tool to do what they want to do, any potential pitfalls or things to be wary of in using such a solution, or even just a simple explanation of what the tool is and what it's doing for you.  (This can be at a very high level; just a small paragraph will suffice.)